# How do I remove the top and bottom spacing from the Material Horizontal Progress Bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, material-design

I have done the same thing with the Holo Progress Bar by editing the drawable pngs to remove the padding from the outside of the file, however I cannot find a png drawable for the Material Bar. If someone could point me to how to find it that would be great!

I have seen people suggesting that I simply set the ProgressBar to have negative top or bottom margins but that is not really a proper solution and is not consistent across different phones.

My XML currently looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ticket_state_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and style:

```
<style name="linear_progress" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint">@color/progress_bar_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/progress_bar_yellow_background</item>
</style>
```

At the moment the ProgressBar appears a few pixels above the bottom of the header although that space is also covered by the ProgressBar view. I wish for the Bar itself to sit flush against the bottom of the header. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer :)

Comment: Is the `ProgressBar` the only thing inside your Layout? Try using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of "wrap_content"

Comment: Unfortunately the frame layout is much larger as it represents a block of colour with the progress bar at the bottom of it. However I could try putting the ProgressBar into another view with a specified height. I'll try that and come back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Add negative margins (`android:layout_marginTop` and `android:layout_marginBottom`):

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id = "@+id/myProgressBar"
  style = "?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"/>
```